# How to set am pm in javascript clock

Tags: javascript

```
function ShowTime() {
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("lblTime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000); // Here 1000(milliseconds) means one 1 Sec  
}
```

this code to displays time in a label but it always shows am only?
what is the way to display am pm correctly according to time (ist+5.30).
or is there any other way to display time without refreshing page

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. It's showing PM for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your current time might be AM so its showing as AM. change your system time manually to PM and then check.

**fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/Bpvpa/1/**

**html:**

```
<div id="lblTime"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
function ShowTime() {
    document.getElementById("lblTime").innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}
setInterval(ShowTime, 1000); // Here 1000(milliseconds) means one 1 Sec
```